# Why is there no operator +/- for a bidirectional iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator

My own reasoning for it is that there is no random access and there is no way to know the bounds. But then why do we have `std::advance`? [EDIT] And come to think of it, why is there no `std::deadvance` (for lack of a better word)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right; the requirements for `operator+/-` is that it be an `O(1)` operation, which cannot be met by bidirectional iterators. `std::advance` has no such speed requirement (but will use it when available, e.g., for random access iterators).

Note that boost has `boost::next` and `boost::prior` implementations for iterators; I'm not sure what their status is on standardization but if it's in boost it's solid.

Answer (score 3):

The rational for `std::advance` is that it should be obvious that you *really* intended to use it, even if it is not O(1).

You don't need a `std::deadvance` as you can use `std::advance` with a negative distance (for bidirectional iterators).

Answer (score 2):

The reason we have `std::advance` is that it provides a way to advance an iterator *using the most effiecient way supported by that iterator*.

Comment: If the bidirectional iterator has the overloaded +/-, then if I type `someListItr + 5` is it not the most efficient way to advance there as well (even if `someListItr` belongs to a random access container)?